# How to set filter value?

Tags: 7, views

I want to use `$view->set_exposed_input()` to set my date filter values(date,month).
But my my knowledge about  php is weak;can you help me?
This is  php code that i using but it's not work

```
$view->set_exposed_input(array(
'f1' => $f1,
'f2' =>  array (
                 'year' => $year,
                 'month' => $month));
```